# How to find the required arguments of a function object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function, `f`:

```
def f(required_arg, optional_arg=None):
    pass
```

How can I return a list of *required* argument names of `f`?

Using `isinstance` on the results of [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> import inspect 
>>> params = inspect.signature(f).parameters    
>>> for arg_name, v in params.items():
>>>     print(v.default)
>>>     print(arg_name, isinstance(v.default, inspect._empty))
>>>     print(arg_name, isinstance(v.default, inspect.Parameter.empty))
<class 'inspect._empty'>
required_arg False
required_arg False
None
optional_arg False
optional_arg False
```

Comment: @GreekCloakGuy yes, that won't work at all in my case.  I am working on a unittest metaclass that dynamically adds tests and need to know which arguments are required, so that I can auto fail that particular test if the argument wasn't included in the class definition.

Comment: Upon some testing, have you tried checking `v.default == inspect._empty` instead of `isinstance(v.default, inspect._empty)`? As in, the value is literally the class itself, not an instance of the class, or so it seems from some experimentation on my end

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy yeah thats it thanks.  I'm guessing the recommended approach would be to use `is` over `==`, but I can't think of any drawbacks to using a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `is` instead of `isinstance`:

```
>>> import inspect 
>>> params = inspect.signature(f).parameters    
>>> for arg_name, v in params.items():
>>>     print(v.default is inspect._empty)
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what @GreenCloakGuy is referring to in his comment:

```
def f(required_arg, optional_arg=None):
    """Directive on what this function is intended to accomplish.

    Args:
        required_arg (str): Argument used to ... thing.
        optional_arg (str): Argument used to ... other thing.

    """
    pass
```

Calling `help(f)` will produce this output for the user:

#### Output:

```
Help on function f in module __main__:

f(required_arg, optional_arg=None)
    Directive on what this function is intended to accomplish.

    Args:
        required_arg (str): Argument used to ... thing.
        optional_arg (str): Argument used to ... other thing.
```

Comment: This might help others asking this question, but definitely won't help in my situation.  See the comment under my question for an explanation.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica - Understood.  I'll leave the answer posted in case it can help others.  Sorry it's not what you're after.